# Should all references to a text domain be to my current theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, debug, textdomain

I'm running Theme Check on a theme I've inherited and I've come across lots of recommendations like this one:

```
RECOMMENDED: Text domain problems in loop.php. The twentyten text domain is being used!
```

The site has no plans for being translated, so what's the best thing to do in this situation? Replace every reference to `twentyten` to my theme's text domain, or just remove all references of a text domain at all?

The WordPress documentation is a little confusing :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all the translation references if you don't plan on translating it. You can also leave it in place, it shouldn't hurt anything..

If you want to remove it, go through your theme files and find references to `__(' Your Text', 'Domain')` and just change it to the "Your Text" portion. (Sometimes, you may even see `_e('Your Text, 'Domain')`).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan on translating it, you should be able to remove the text domain references without any trouble. They are not required.

Comment: ...but you will hate yourself if you ever change your mind

Comment: True. However, the question does indicate that there are no plans to do so (which generally means no foreseen reason to do so).